# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for a method in application helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a method called crumbs that is saying undefined method.  I am importing code from a sinatra app and trying to make it work with a rails app.

here is the method:

```
def crumbs
primary, secondary = current_link
return {
    primary:   { icon: menu[primary.to_sym][:primary][:icon], label: menu[primary.to_sym][:primary][:label]},
    secondary: {
        icon:  menu[primary.to_sym][:items][secondary.to_sym][:icon],
        label: menu[primary.to_sym][:items][secondary.to_sym][:label]
    }
}
end
```

Here are other methods included within the method:

```
 def menu
  return {
    dashboard: {
        primary: { link: "dashboard", icon: "icon-dashboard", label: "Dashboard" },
        items: {
            dashboard: { icon: "icon-dashboard", label: "Dashboard" }
        }
    },
    ui_lab: {
        primary: { link: "buttons", icon: "icon-beaker", label: "UI Lab" },
        items: {
            buttons: { icon: "icon-hand-up",       label: "Buttons" },
            general: { icon: "icon-beaker",        label: "General elements" },
            icons:   { icon: "icon-info-sign",     label: "Icons"},
            grid:    { icon: "icon-th-large",      label: "Grid"},
            tables:  { icon: "icon-table",         label: "Tables"},
            widgets: { icon: "icon-plus-sign-alt", label: "Widgets"},
        }
    },
    forms: {
        primary: { link: "forms", icon: "icon-edit", label: "Forms" },
        items: {
            forms: { icon: "icon-edit", label: "Form Elements" }
        }
    },
    charts: {
        primary: { link: "charts", icon: "icon-bar-chart", label: "Charts"},
        items: {
            charts: { icon: "icon-bar-chart", label: "Charts"}
        }
    },
    other: {
        primary: { link: "wizard", icon: "icon-link", label: "Others"},
        items: {
            wizard: { icon: "icon-magic", label: "Wizard" },
            login: { icon: "icon-user", label: "Login Page" },
            sign_up: { icon: "icon-user", label: "Sign Up Page" },
            full_calendar: { icon: "icon-calendar", label: "Full Calendar" },
            error404: { icon: "icon-ban-circle", label: "Error 404 page" },
        }
    }
}
end
```

As well as this one:

```
def current_link
root_path = "/"
current_route = request.url.split("/") # pages/dashboard/stats.html -> ['dashboard', 'stats.html']
return current_route.compact.first, current_route.compact.split(".").first
end
```

In the view this is what is being called:

```
      <i class="<%= crumbs[:secondary][:icon] %>"></i>
        <%= crumbs[:secondary][:label] %>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using [:symbol] on a chain that is returning nil - menu[primary.to_sym] #=> nil[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to hunt these down is to replace your `[]` calls with calls to `:fetch`.  When it blows up it'll return a `KeyError` telling you which key is missing:

```
> mystery = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}

> mystery[:d][:q]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

> mystery.fetch(:d).fetch(:q)
KeyError: key not found: :d
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply define the missing method for nil:

```
def nil.[] x
  puts "You hit the jackpot!!! You win #{x}!!!"
  # Or come up with the behavior according to your own needs.
end
```

Jokes aside, your question does not provide enough information to identify the real problem of yours. It seems that one or more of your hashes does not contain the keys searched for, and you then attempt to send `#[]` method to it. Try `Object#try` method from `ActiveSupport`, or write:

```
def crumbs
  primary, secondary = current_link
  return {
    primary: { icon: ( menu[primary.to_sym][:primary][:icon] rescue nil ),
               label: ( menu[primary.to_sym][:primary][:label]} rescue nil ),
    secondary:
      { icon: ( menu[primary.to_sym][:items][secondary.to_sym][:icon] rescue nil ),
        label: ( menu[primary.to_sym][:items][secondary.to_sym][:label] rescue nil )
      }
    }
end
```